# Where to call an Action when user removes an uploaded image in GWTUpload?

Tags: gwt, gwtupload

I am using GWTUpload , the library is in here https://code.google.com/p/gwtupload/

The Example code at client side found on that website has this structure:

```
 // Attach an image to the pictures viewer
private OnLoadPreloadedImageHandler showImage = new OnLoadPreloadedImageHandler() {
    public void onLoad(PreloadedImage image) {
      //showImageFlowPanel code solution 1
      image.setWidth("75px");
      showImageFlowPanel.add(image);
    }
};


private IUploader.OnFinishUploaderHandler onFinishUploaderHandler = new IUploader.OnFinishUploaderHandler() {
      public void onFinish(IUploader uploader) {
        if (uploader.getStatus() == Status.SUCCESS) {

          new PreloadedImage(uploader.fileUrl(), showImage);

          UploadedInfo info = uploader.getServerInfo();

          String headShotImageUrl="http://"+Window.Location.getHost()+"/" +"images/uploaded/"+info.message;
          //headShotImage code solution 2
          if(!"".equals(headShotImageUrl) && UriUtils.isSafeUri(headShotImageUrl)){
              headShotImage.setUrl(UriUtils.fromString(headShotImageUrl));
          }



        }
      }
    };
```

The example uses `showImageFlowPanel` (solution 1) to store the image but I want to store the image inside `headShotImage` which take the url after user uploaded image successfully, see the `headShotImage` (solution 2) code above.

Ok, the headShotImage code work fine but I dont know how to remove it when users remove the image. If I use `showImageFlowPanel` as in the solution 1 then the program remove the image automatically for me and I do not need to do anything.

So my question is "**Where to call an Action when user removes an uploaded image in GWTUpload?**"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to use `setOnCancelUploaderHandler`. Take a look to this code took from the demo.

```
// When the user clicks a cancel button we get an event
uploader.addOnCancelUploadHandler ( 
  new IUploader.OnCancelUploaderHandler() {
    public void onCancel(IUploader uploader) {
      for (String iname : uploader.getServerMessage().getUploadedFieldNames()) {
        // loadedImages is an temporary table where we are adding all uploaded files
        // indexed by field name
        Widget w = loadedImages.get(iname);
        if (w != null) {
          w.removeFromParent();
        loadedImages.remove(uploader.getInputName());
       }
     }
   }
});
```

Comment: there is no "setOnCancelUploadHandler" but only "addOnCancelUploadHandler". Besides, Image has no .get & .remove method. Ap part from that, it works fine

Comment: You are right, I copied a pasted code and changed a little bit, [see original](https://github.com/manolo/gwtupload/blob/master/samples/src/main/java/gwtuploadsample/client/ChismesUploadSample.java#L195) lines #195 and #114. Updated comment. The remove method is the panel in my demo, you have to use whatever method you have in your widgets, but the important thing is that you can handle the event and the file identifier.